# What is the relationship between cause and effect as enunciated by Maharishi Kanada?

Tags: kanada, vaisheshika, shad-darshana, vaisheshika-sutra

*[Maharshi Kanada](http://firstip.org/legendary-scientists/maharshi-kanada-the-propunder-of-atomic-theory600-bce)* was the founder of the Vaisheshika school of thought, one of the [Shad Darshanas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dar%C5%9Bana) in Hinduism. He wrote the [Vaisheshika Sutras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vai%C5%9Be%E1%B9%A3ika_S%C5%ABtra), the most prominent text of this school.

What does he say about the relationship between cause and effect?

Answer (score 3):

*Maharishi Kanada* talks about the relationship between cause and effect in the following Shlokas:

[Shloka 1.2.1](https://archive.org/stream/thevaiasesikasut00kanauoft#page/34/mode/2up).

> कारणभवात् कार्य्याभावः   ।। १ । २ । १ ।।

कारणभवात्  (Kaaranabhaavaat), from the non-existence of cause

कार्य्याभावः  (Kaaryyabhaavah), non-existence of effect

> **Non-existence of effect (follows) from the non-existence of cause**

[Shloka 1.2.2](https://archive.org/stream/thevaiasesikasut00kanauoft#page/36/mode/2up).

> न तु कार्य्याभावात् कारणभावः   ।। १ । २ । २ ।।

न (Na), not

तु (Tu), but

कार्य्याभावात् (Kaaryyabhaavat), from non-existence of effect

कारणभावः (Kaaranabhaavah), non-existence of causes

> **But non-existence of cause (does) not (follow) from the non-existence**
>   **of effect**

[Shloka 2.1.24](https://archive.org/stream/thevaiasesikasut00kanauoft#page/68/mode/2up).

> कारणगुणपूर्व्वकः कार्य्यगुणो दृष्टः  ।। २ । १ । २४ ।।

कारणगुणपूर्व्वकः (Kaarana-guna-poorvakah), preceded by the attributes of cause

कार्य्यगुणः  (Kaaryya-gunah), attributes of the effect

दृष्टः (Drishtah), is seen or observed

> **The Attribute of the effect is seen to be preceded by the Attribute of the cause**

e.g. The colour (attribute) of an object is perceived before any attribute of the Earth element (cause)

Reference used: [The Vaisesika sutras of Kanada -  Translated by Nandalal Sinha](https://archive.org/details/thevaiasesikasut00kanauoft)

Comment: You may be interested in my question here, about an Advaita critique of the theory of cause and effect described in your answer: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/12109/36

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Thanks for sharing. Yup, both are opposite but both are true :)