# What is the relationship between cause and effect according to Nyaya Sutras?

Tags: advaita, nyaya, vaisheshika, nyaya-sutra

[Nyaya Sutra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ny%C4%81ya_S%C5%ABtras#Theory_of_causality), written by Maharishi Gautama,  is the foundational text of the Nyaya school of thought, one of the Shad-Darshanas in Hinduism.

Amongst other things, this text talks about the [theory of causality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ny%C4%81ya_S%C5%ABtras#Theory_of_causality). The reference provides interpretations by multiple authors on such a relationship.

What are the Shlokas in the Nyaya Sutras which give the essence of relationship between cause and effect? I am looking for the original Shlokas with translation.

For those who are interested in such a relationship, [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/12064/what-is-the-relationship-between-cause-and-effect-as-enunciated-by-maharishi-kan) question talks about the Viasheshika viewpoint on the cause and effect relationship. [This](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/12109/what-is-the-advaita-argument-against-real-things-being-causes) question talks about the Advaita viewpoint.

Comment: The Nyaya and Vaisheshika schools had the same notion of cause, in fact the question of mine that you linked to is about an Advaita critique of the Nyaya school's theory of cause and effect.

Comment: The wiki article I shared says that Nyaya rejects supernatural causes. I have not read the Vaisheshika Sutras fully but things like Atman, Manas are considered causes.