# What is the relationship between cause and effect as enunciated in the Yoga Vasistha?

Tags: rama, vashishta, yoga-vashishtha

[Yoga Vashishtha](http://estudantedavedanta.net/The-Supreme-Yoga-Swami-Venkatesananda.pdf) is a text in which Maharishi Vashishtha gives knowledge to Shri Rama. It is in the form of conversation between the two of them.

How is the relationship between cause and effect explained in this text?

For those interested, the aforementioned relation is also discussed in these questions: in [Vaisheshika Sutras](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/12064/what-is-the-relationship-between-cause-and-effect-as-enunciated-by-maharishi-kan), [Nyaya Sutras](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/12245/what-is-the-relationship-between-cause-and-effect-according-to-nyaya-sutras) and [Advaita](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/12109/what-is-the-advaita-argument-for-why-causes-cant-have-real-existence).

Answer (score 1):

Shri Rama goes on a pilgrimage and when he returns, there is a profound change in him. He keeps to his own company. His father, king Dasharatha asks him about it but Rama replies that nothing is wrong.

Dasharatha then turns to sage Vashishtha to figure out what is going on. Maharishi Valmiki narrates the conversation thus:

> ...Inevitably Dasharatha turned to sage Vashishtha for the answers. The
>   sage enigmatically answered: "Surely, there is some reason why Rama
>   behaves in this manner. **Even as in this world no great changes take
>   place before the coming into being of their cause, viz., the cosmic
>   elements; changes like anger, despondency and joy do not manifest in
>   the behaviour of noble ones without proper cause.**" Dasharatha did not
>   wish to probe further..

Source: http://estudantedavedanta.net/The-Supreme-Yoga-Swami-Venkatesananda.pdf